# Attempting to insert data into a SQL Server table with no primary key or clustered index intermittently comes up with strange bulk load error

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a stored procedure in SQL Server which inserts data from a staging table into a fact table. This is first joined onto various dimension tables to get their id columns.

Intermittently, it will throw the following error:

> ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot bulk load. The bulk data stream was incorrectly specified as sorted or the data violates a uniqueness constraint imposed by the target table. Sort order incorrect for the following two rows: primary key of first row: (305603, 0xedd9f90001001a00), primary key of second row: (245634, 0x0832680003003200). (4819) (SQLExecDirectW)')

*(The two rows mentioned in the error message usually change each time the error occurs)*

The fact table doesn't have any primary key or clustered index, although it does have a few non-clustered indexes, so the error message is really confusing me.

The dimension tables DO have primary keys, but the fact table has no foreign keys related to them.

I have searched for hours on the internet but don't seem to have found a solution.

Does anybody know why I would receive such an error in this case? any help would be appreciated. We are using Azure SQL database.

I am aware that the database is badly designed however it was created before my time.

Comment: What of the first part of the message, "the bulk data stream was incorrectly specified as sorted"? Hook up a profiler to see if the `INSERT BULK` has a sort order hint. Generally this doesn't happen on its own, but depending on your client technology something may have gotten clever. And per the second part, is there any *uniqueness* constraint on the table, perhaps in the form of unique non-clustered indexes, that the data might be violating, not necessarily a PK? The message doesn't seem to indicate that but it's worth checking.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your suggestion. I am checking the SQL in the profiler but there is no sort order hint. Also it is ```INSERT INTO``` , not ```INSERT BULK``` . None of the indexes have unique constraints.

Comment: That might be an Azure thing then -- an `INSERT INTO` normally does not cause a bulk load (with `TABLOCK` you get minimal logging and even parallelism if there are no non-clustered indexes, but I don't think that counts as a bulk load for engine purposes). Note that `INSERT BULK` is not a command you issue, but the (hidden) command that the profiler shows if a client API uses the T-SQL bulk load interface.