# Data stream was incorrectly specified as sorted or the data violates a uniqueness constraint imposed by the target table error message on insert into

Tags: sql-server, indexing

On `INSERT INTO` of several customer data stored in a migration table into the actual production table I get the following error message:

> Msg 4819, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
> Cannot bulk load. The bulk data stream was incorrectly specified as sorted or the data violates a uniqueness constraint imposed by the target table. Sort order incorrect for the following two rows: primary key of first row: (90000004, 0), primary key of second row: (60681605, 0).

**Description of operation**

The source table as well as the target table contains several customer data, such as firstname, lastname, postal address among others.
The "primary key" of the target table is a combination of customer number and a so called version number (when greater than 0 it's indicating that there is a newer postal address in the future - so it's typically 0).

Its not a real primary key but a non-clustered unique index.
The script is used by an interface that's inserting this customer data coming from a foreign system into our crm system. The interface exists already several years and now a change has to be made that considers that there are active and also inactive customers.

Changes are made in the assignment of the new customer number. Whereas active customers get a customer number above the range of 90'000'000 inactive customers get a lower customer number according to the next free customer number in the target system.

All customer data with customer number greater 90'000'000 will every time the interface runs, be deleted an written anew.

All customer data with customer numbers within the actual target system number range will once be written and then will not be edited further on.

So the source table contains customer numbers in the range about something like 46'057'654 and > 90'000'000. In total there are about 1800 customers in this interface.

Technically its pure SQL code, the actual `INSERT INTO` statement is stored in a stored procedure.

**Testing environment**

All the tests are made in a testing environment on a database copied from the actual production database. There the interface is perfectly running, but there isn't the distinction between active and inactive customers yet.

**Deprecated table and index structure**

The table structure is grown by the year so it's not following best practices on its architecture such as would be implemented when now creating this table from scratch regarding all requirements demanded to it.

**Thoughts made**

Based on the data in the source table I would assume that there couldn't really be a problem with the data since it contains no data that would cause problems with the indexes on the target table such as duplicates of customer numbers or any other data stored in an index. As i mentioned before the only difference in the source table on the testing environment compared to the source table on the productive environment is the use of two different number ranges.

**Search efforts made**

I searched for several hours looking for anything usable solving this problem. Most of the articles I found are related to

- SQL azure (problem is in "normal" SQL server) or to SQL Server 2014
  *(used version --> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU31-GDR) (KB5021126) - 14.0.3460.9 (X64) | Jan 25 2023 08:42:43 | Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation | Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor))*
- bulk load issues directly from a csv or txt-File.
- The following article seems to face the same or similar issue but is also not solved or explained yet.
  [Attempting to insert data into a SQL Server table with no primary key or clustered index intermittently comes up with strange bulk load error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73907988/attempting-to-insert-data-into-a-sql-server-table-with-no-primary-key-or-cluster)

**Tries made**

To successfull insert the data into the target table, I tried to split the data into two sections, one with the customer numbers greater than 90'000'000 and a second one with the customer numbers lower than 90'000'000. The same error occured.
As mentioned above on the target table are several indexes. I tried to deactivate the one I thought is causing the error message. Now the error message is quite the same only the shown values changed indicating that now another index of the target table is causing the problem.
I repeated this approach always getting quite the same error message indicating that its now because of another index.

---

**Preliminary remark**

Meanwhile I found a solution for the problem, however I can just
explain what I changed but not why this change has such impact. So I'm not quite sure if this comment actually would be accepted as answer.

**Suggested solution**

Our development team added a new unique index on the target table. The index is on a uniqueidentifier column. The colums constraint actually allows inserting NULL values whereas the new index on that column denies it while making it unique.
In the past this column was initialized with a NULL-Value by the `INSERT INTO`. Now exactly this is causing the error message. Changing the inserted NULL-Value to NEWID() solved the problem.
I tried to reconstruct the actual table with fewer columns on a sample database using the same indexes as on the target table. Trying to insert NULL-Values on the column concerned shows the error message:

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 27
> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Address' with unique index 'ix_AddressId'. The duplicate key value is ().

which I would expect in the described case above, too.

Comment: That's a lot of info, but you never posted your BCP code. Does it by any chance have `-h "ORDER...."` in it? I suggest you also post the DDL of the target table. i.e. does it have a PK or not? This is all pretty critical info

Comment: Hi Nick
Sorry for the somewhat clumsy call back. What do you understand under the abbreviation bcp? The target table has no real primary key but an unique index as i described in the question.

Comment: Oh apologies I didn't read properly, thought you weer using `BCP.EXE` to load this data. But you're using `INSERT INTO` So what does the SQL code look like (i.e. post the statement)? Also what do the source and target tables look like (i.e. post the table DDL). This is a very strange error. I would be inclined to run `DBCC CHECKDB` first. Also please run `SELECT @@VERSION` and paste the results. You might also want to drop and recreate all indexes. Also, typically you would actual disable the indexes and load and rebuild afterwards. That might give you some more clues.

Comment: I've only ever seen this error when using the bulk load options either `bcp.exe` or `FROM OPENROWSET(BULK` or using `SqlBulkCopy` in C#, or when passing a Table Valued Parameter (which has a key defined) with incorrect data

Comment: Can you get the execution plan for the statement that is failing? Also did you run CHECKDB as suggested above? Maybe the insert has a `DMLRequestSort`  that ought to be met by an index on the source but there is some corruption in the source